# Only getting coordinates of last images in CSV file while inference. Python

Tags: python, csv

This is my code to get the coordinates of BB. I am iterating through images. Each image contain more then one detected BB. I want to store all coordinates in CSV file. I am adding xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax along with filename to list in one loop. Then tried to write each coordinate into CSV file using writerow using another loop. But in csv file i am getting the coordinates of last image, it seems that all other coordinates are get overwritten, Can any one make changes in this code to get all coordinates of all iterating images.

```
#run detector on test image
#it takes a little longer on the first run and then runs at normal speed.
import random
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import csv
from csv import writer
import pandas as pd

count=0
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS =   glob.glob('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Final_datasets/UTiV/test/*.jpg')
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
    if count < 4:

       #image_path = random.choice(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)

       file_name_ext=os.path.basename(image_path)
       file_name=os.path.splitext(file_name_ext)[0]

       image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
       img = Image.open(image_path)
       # image_np = cv2.imread(image_path)

       # Things to try:
       # Flip horizontally
       # image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

       # Convert image to grayscale
       # image_np = np.tile(
       #     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

       input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(
        np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)


        height, width, _ = image_np.shape

        i = 0
        list1=[]
        list2=[]
        field_names = ['filename','xmin','ymin','xmax','ymax']
      
        # open CSV file and assign header
        with open("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/UrduDetection/CSV_file/coordinates.csv", 'w') as file:
           dw = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=field_names)
           dw.writeheader()
      
        # display csv file
        fileContent = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/UrduDetection/CSV_file/coordinates.csv")
        fileContent

        for box,score,cls in zip(detections['detection_boxes']  [0],detections['detection_scores'][0],detections['detection_classes'][0]):
            if score >= 0.5: # or any other value
                xmin = int(box[1]*width)
                ymin = int(box[0]*height)
                xmax = int(box[3]*width)
                ymax = int(box[2]*height)
                list1.append((file_name,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax))
        #print(list)

        for i in list1:
            with   open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/UrduDetection/CSV_file/coordinates.csv','a',newline='') as fd:
            writer_object = csv.writer(fd)
            writer_object.writerow(i)
        print(list1)


    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.5,
          agnostic_mode=False,
    )

    plt.figure(figsize=(12,16))
    plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
    plt.show()

else:
    break
count = count+1
```

Comment: Opening a file in `"w"` mode overwrites the current contents; you do this for each image.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: I am using 'a' while writing rows in CSV, 'w' is when I wrote field names in CSV.

Comment: I think my coordinates list and loop are not at right place but I am not able find.

Comment: Every time you write the field names (which you do for each image path), you "erase" what was previously in the file.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much. You can add it in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file in "w" mode overwrites the current contents (effectively erasing the previous contents); you do this for each image path, when you write the field names.